# inputting a file not from a subdirectory

Tags: input, include

I apologise if this question has already been addressed.

Say I have a set up like this:

I have a main folder in which I have both **preamble.tex** and a folder **sub_1**. In **sub_1**, there is another folder **sub_2** - and in **sub_2** there is **my_file.tex**

What must I write in my_file.tex in order to input preamble.tex? A cursory google and tex.stackexchange search of "input" and "different directory" seems only to address the case when, say,  the preamble is located in some subdirectory of where the main file is.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `\input{../../preamble}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the comments, Daniel answered my question.

Moreover, if one wants to input a file n *levels* above your file (file_name.tex), write `\input{` then `../` n times, and then `file_name}`.

Comment: Meta-comment: this is not TeX-specific; it's just the way that relative paths are written in UNIX operating systems (in Windows, you turn the slashes around, but as Joseph Wright reminded me, TeX always uses forward slashes even in Windows).

Comment: I would recommend using `\def\Path{../..}`, and then use `\input{\Path/premable}`, in case you ever decide to change the hierarchy.

Comment: One should mention that `\include` will not work for files above the current directory.

Comment: @RyanReich: Meta-meta-comment: Path separation in Windows is good for quite some myths. In fact, the Win32/64 subsystems (at the API level) have always supported *both*, slashes and backslashes as path separator; the NT kernel under the hood even uses **only** forward slashes. The support of backslashes (and drive letters, which inside the kernel are just symbolic links, somewhat like UNIX) is a compatibility inheritance from DOS. It's only the shell (`cmd.exe`) that insists on backslashes and some applications that use archaic algorithms to sanitize file paths.